# Looking a solution to extract Email address with iMacros

Tags: email, extract, imacros

I am not good in coding but I managed to create this simple macro to extract email address from a specific page with iMacros for Firefox.

The macro works flawlessly... Except

There is a little problem with extracted data.

This is the extracted data:

> "    Some Name  ","some@domain.comHello"
>
> "    Some Other Name  ","other@domain.netThis"
>
> "    Any Name  ","some@domain.com.twSomeothertext"

I believe there is a line break and/or pharagraph problem with the email fields. There are also 4 space at the begining and 2 spaces at the end of the Name field.
I want to get rid of it and fix the email extraction problem.

This is what i want:

> "Some Name","some@domain.com"
>
> "Some Other Name","other@domain.net"
>
> "Any Name","some@domain.com.tw"

And that is the code

```
VERSION BUILD=8970419 RECORDER=FX
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAB T=1
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type({{!loop}})>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>A>SPAN" BUTTON=0 MODIFIERS="ctrl"
TAB T=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:profile-display-name EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR1 {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:profile EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR2 EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/(([^<>()[\\]\\\.,;:\\s@\\\"]+(\\.[^<>()[\\]\\\.,;:\\s@\\\"]+)*)|(\\\".+\\\"))@((\\[[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\])|(([a-zA-Z\\-0-9]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))/g)[0];")
SET !EXTRACT NULL
SET !EXTRACT {{!VAR1}}[EXTRACT]{{!VAR2}}
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=D:\ FILE=Contacts.txt
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
'URL GOTO=javascript:window.scrollBy(0,2000)
```

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the folowing corrections:

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.trim();")
```

and

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:profile EXTRACT=HTM
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much
I used the code
extract commented posts on facebook  that are awesome

```
VERSION BUILD=8970419 RECORDER=FX
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAB T=1
SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:UFICommentBody* EXTRACT=HTM
SET !VAR2 EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/(([^<>()[\\]\\\.,;:\\s@\\\"]+(\\.[^<>()[\\]\\\.,;:\\s@\\\"]+)*)|(\\\".+\\\"))@((\\[[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\])|(([a-zA-Z\\-0-9]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))/g)[0];")
SET !EXTRACT {{!VAR2}}
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=D:\ FILE=MAIL_FB.txt
```